# Pagination : Compile Error: expecting a left angle bracket, found 'lstAccount' at line 11 column 16

Tags: visualforce, error, pagination

I'm trying to do pagination based on offset.Below is the code

Controller class :

```
public with sharing class PagingController {

    public PagingController (){
        CountTotalRecords= [select count() from Account];
    }

    public Integer CountTotalRecords{get;set;}
    public String QueryString {get;set;}
    public Integer OffsetSize = 0;
    private Integer QueryLimit = 5;
    public list lstAccount;

    public list getAccounts(){
        lstAccount = new list();
        lstAccount = [Select id, Name, BillingCity, BillingState, Phone from Account order by Name limit :QueryLimit offset :OffsetSize];
        return lstAccount;
    }

    public Boolean getDisablePrevious(){
        if(OffsetSize>0){
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    public Boolean getDisableNext() {
        if (OffsetSize + QueryLimit < countTotalRecords){
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    public PageReference Next() {
        OffsetSize += QueryLimit;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference Previous() {
        OffsetSize -= QueryLimit;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Page :

```
<apex:page controller="PagingController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts" id="pgBlock">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="acc" id="pgTable">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingCity}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingState}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!Previous}" rerender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                    status="status" disabled="{!DisablePrevious}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}" reRender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                    status="status" disabled="{!DisableNext}" />
                <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Please Wait..."/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Its giving me an error as described in the heading which is :

> Compile Error: expecting a left angle bracket, found 'lstAccount' at
>   line 11 column 16

Please help me to code it right to get out of this error.

Comment: I suggest you look at other code that makes use of lists and combine that information with the error message which is pretty specific.

Comment: @Keith I'm really stuck with this error . I tried collecting information but no joy.Help will be appreciated.

Comment: @user7067 Its is now giving the following error ... Error: Compile Error: expecting a left angle bracket, found 'getAccounts' at line 13 column 16

Comment: remove line 13, no use if you are again reinitialize it on line 14

Answer (score 2):

It is syntax error, declaration of list should be like this:

```
public List<Account> lstAccount;
```

on line no 11

Answer (score 1):

Lists can be declared in two ways, Both are useful and depend on your preference for syntax.

```
public list lstAccount;

    public list getAccounts(){
        lstAccount = new list();
```

should be

```
public Account[] lstAccount;

    public list getAccounts(){
        lstAccount = new Account[]{};

OR

public list<Account> lstAccount;

    public list getAccounts(){
        lstAccount = new list<Account>();
```